# Cannot increment a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, increment

I'm trying to create a script to count the number of hidden and non-hidden files in a folder where the script is run.
However, I run into an issue where I cannot increment variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

#A simple script to count the number of hidden and non-hidden files in the folder this script is run in

#Variables to store the number of hidden and non-hidden files and folders
#Variables with a 'h' at the end represent hidden items

files=0
fileh=0

#List all files and folders
#Use grep to folder entries beginning with '-', which are files
#Return the 9th word in the string which is the filename
#Read the filename into the variable 'fls'
ls -al | grep ^- | awk '{print $9}' | while read fls

#If the filename begins, with a dot, it is a hidden file
do
    if [[ $fls == .* ]]
    then
        #Therefore increment the number of hidden files by one
        let fileh++
    else
        #Else, increment the number if non-hidden files by one
        let files++
    fi
done

#Print out the two numbers
echo $files 'non-hidden files'
echo $fileh 'hidden files'

#When I run this script, the output is always zero for both variables
#I don't know why this doesn't work?!
```

The output of this script is as follows:

```
jai@L502X~$ ./script.sh 
0 non-hidden files
0 hidden files
```

Comment: quote your increments like `let "fileh++"`

Comment: It did not make any difference.

Comment: I feel like there is probably an easier way:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens on the right hand side of a `|` happens in a subshell. Changes to variables in a subshell don't propagate back to the parent shell.

Common workaround: don't use a pipe, use Process substitution:

```
while read fls ; do
   ...
done < <(ls -al | grep ^- | awk '{print $9}')
```

Comment: Thanks, you solution works! I do understand the explanation that you gave, however, I don't understand the syntax used.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to increment a variable using `let`, you have to quote your expression, like in

```
let "i++"
```

However, I personally prefer to use the double-parentheses syntax, which is

```
((i++))
# or, if you want a pre-fixed increment
((++i))
```

Plus, you can use a way shorter syntax for your `if` statement, using `&&` and `||`:

```
[[ $fls == .* ]] && ((++fileh)) || ((++files))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote the variable increment

```
let "fileh++"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the "increment" question, but a much easier script to do what you're trying to do:

```
files=`find . -type f`
echo "non-hidden files " `echo "$files" | egrep -v "[/]\.[^/]+$" | wc -l`
echo "hidden files " `echo "$files" | egrep "[/]\.[^/]+$" | wc -l`
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm doing a challenge where I can't use the commands 'find' 'du' 'locate' or any recursive function.