# bash, RANDOM generator with while read

Tags: bash

```
printf "%s\n" ${RANDOM}{,,,,,} |
    while read num
    do
        (( num > ${biggest:=0} )) && biggest=$num
    done
printf "The biggest number is: %d\n" "$biggest"
```

somehow i can't figure out whats wrong, tried for days and can't find nothing. tried different things with ${num} and {$num} but I don't know the syntax to well...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27677804/1030675

Comment: This is [Bash FAQ 24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Sadly, the top answer in the duplicate is not an answer.

Comment: none of those helps... why mark this as dublicate then...